# Distribution Profile not visisble in XCode

Tags: ios, code-signing

I know this may seem similar to other questions on here but just here me out. I'm trying to submit an iOS app to the store for a client, but cannot get his Distribution profile to show up in Edit>Project> Code Signing menu. I have downloaded and installed it. The strange thing  is that it appears in the "Organizer." I have cleaned the project repeatedly and deleted my distribution profile. I'm on the verge of reinstalling XCode and the iOS SDK and am hoping that there is a better and faster way to solve this problem.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this. I had to delete and reinstall XCode after deleting all my provisioning and distribution profiles form my system